# Recursive sort that doesn't require list splicing?

Tags: recursion, sorting

I was just wondering if there was some form of sort algorithm that doesn't require any form of splicing of the original list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "splicing" mean in this context?  Straight insertion sort, sometimes described as the "first decent sorting algorithm", proceeds by constructing the sorted output without necessarily changing the input list.  However entries from the original list are inserted one at a time into the output list.  Also algorithms such as the infamous "bubble sort" proceed by comparing and possibly transposing adjacent elements in the original list.  Does this constitute "splicing"?

Comment: Just no splitting up of the original list into smaller pieces at all. (think merge sort)

Comment: So bubble sort (transposing adjacent elements) is allowed?

Comment: yes, that's what I was thinking. However i'm not sure how to approach that.

Comment: If I may ask, how does the requirement of a "recursive sort" figure in your problem?  A natural use of recursion is to solve a "big" problem by combining the solutions of smaller problems.  Sorting can be done in many ways, some more efficient than others.  Merge sort is not the only algorithm, and almost any algorithm that exists can be artificially construed as a recursive one (even if a more natural presentation is an iterative one).

Comment: Well we have a version of the sort (more or less bubble sort) in a list splicing form: base cases are either length 1,2 which do nothing, and sort values respectively. Then for values greater than 3, it sorts the first 2-thirds of the list recursively, then the second 2-thirds of the list, then the first 2-thirds again. However what we do need is a version that doesn't split up the list at all it seems, as well as it having the same runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good reference for sorting algorithms is Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming* vol. 3, [Sorting and Searching](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201896850), 2nd ed.

We will describe two algorithms mentioned in the Comments above.  The first of these is "straight insertion sorting", which is Knuth's **Program S** in Sec. 5.2.1 "Sorting by Insertion".  He writes: "This method is extremely easy to implement on a computer; in fact the following [Program S] is the shortest decent sorting routine in this book."

Given an input list `L[1..N]` of *distinct* items (for simplicity) and a comparator routine that determines the correct ranking of two items `isLess(X,Y)` by returning true if `X < Y` and false if `X > Y`, we can put the list into a sorted order by calling:

```
sortListByStraightInsertion(L,N,N)
```

if the routine `sortListByStraightInsertion(L,K,N)` is defined as follows:

```
if (K = 0) then return;   /* else */
M := K;
while ( (M < N) and isLess(L[M+1],L[M]) )
{
    swap(L,M,M+1);  /* transpose Mth and M+1st items in L */
    M := M+1;
}
sortListByStraightInsertion(L,K-1,N);  /* tail recursive call */
```

Here recursion is being used for the sake of the Question's premise (that recursion *should* be used) to emulate an iteration.  The effect of `swap` calls within each invocation are to insert `L[K]` at the proper point in the tail portion of `L[K..N]` so that it will be in sorted order when the routine calls itself recursively (or returns).

The second algorithm we describe is "bubble sort", which is Knuth's **Program B** in Sec. 5.2.2 "Sorting by Exchanging", methods that "systematically interchange pairs of elements that are out of order until no more such pairs exist."  He further notes that "straight insertion... can be viewed as an exchange method".

Similarly to the above we will frame this "bubble sort" (also known as *exchange selection*) as a recursive method to be called on a list `L[1..N]` of distinct items, and "reuse" the comparator `isLess` and transposer `swap` already introduced.  The the list may be put into sorted order by calling:

```
sortListByBubbleSort(L,N)
```

if the routine `sortListByBubbleSort(L,N)` is defined recursively as:

```
B := false;
for M := 1 to N-1
{
    if isLess(L[M+1],L[M]) then
    {
        B := true;
        swap(L,M,M+1);
    }
}
if B then sortListByBubbleSort(L,N);  /* recurse, else return */
```

This algorithm repeatedly scans the list for adjacent items that are out of order and transposes them accordingly, until a final scan reveals that all the items are now in their correct order.  The boolean variable `B` is used to record whether or not an exchange occurs during the present invocation of `sortListByBubbleSort`.  A `false` value of `B` indicates no exchange occurred, and thus that the list is now in sort order.